# How do I keep duplicate values across different dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame showing users and login dates, I am struggling to find a solution to use python/pandas leave only users that logged in every unique day.

I need to drop rows where users logged in multiple times per day leaving only 1 row per day for each user and then drop any users who did not log in each unique day.

Dataframe

| Date | User |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/23 | Tom |
| 01/01/23 | Tom |
| 01/03/23 | Andrew |
| 02/03/23 | Andrew |
| 01/03/23 | Barry |
| 01/02/23 | Andrew |

Desired Result

| Date | User |
| --- | --- |
| 01/03/23 | Andrew |
| 02/03/23 | Andrew |
| 01/02/23 | Andrew |

Answer (score 2):

#### Annotated Code

```
# frequency table of user login count per date
s = pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Date'])

# remove the date columns where user has
# logged in more than one time in a given day
s = s.loc[:, ~(s > 1).any()]

# select the rows where user has logged in for all dates
s = s.loc[s.eq(1).all(1), :]

# filter/select the rows where User satisfy's the above condition
df.query('User in @s.index')
```

#### Result

```
       Date    User
2  01/03/23  Andrew
3  02/03/23  Andrew
5  01/02/23  Andrew
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `drop_duplicates()` and `nunique()`

```
#remove all duplicates if both Date and User are duplicated
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

#groupby user and find the unique count to compare to total unique count
df2.loc[df2.groupby('User')['Date'].transform('nunique').eq(df2['Date'].nunique())]
```

Output:

```
       Date    User
2  01/03/23  Andrew
3  02/03/23  Andrew
5  01/02/23  Andrew
```